# Excel VBA userform - using the same form to generate continuous data

Tags: excel, vba

I'm fairly new to VBA. I want to create a userform that will allow the user to use the same form multiple times. Each time the form is used, any data the user inputs, gets added to a variable (the same variable or multiple different ones). When the user has input all the data, they can hit submit and the form will spit out all the data in order.

Example:
Userform with a textbox and 2 command buttons, `Next` and `Submit`.
User inputs `1`, clicks `Next`. User inputs `2`, clicks `Submit`. 
Userform prints out `1, 2`.

How would I go about doing this? Is this even possible?

Comment: Totally possible. It's up to you how and where you want to store the submissions (in a collection, a dictionary, an array, a worksheet...) Then you just retrieve and display those values.

Comment: I'm very new to VBA and writing code in general (I have no background in it). What would be the best way to go about this? I want the user to be able to decide how many times they input data. So some users might only need to use the form once. Others might need 5 instances. I don't need you to write the code for me but if you could point in the right direction, I'd really appreciate it!

Comment: It can be hard to get started on this kind of stuff. I've been there. I've put an example as an answer using the most plain userform on a brand new workbook. Here I'm using an array called `Submissions` to hold the values submitted by the user in `TextBox1`. To get this running after creating the userform and pasting this code in, you can go to your `Immediate` pane (View>>Immediate) and type in `userForm1.Show` and press enter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a quick POC. Consider a plain-jane userform with a textbox and two command buttons. I didn't change the default names here at all. Just added a userform with textbox1, commandbutton1, and commandbutton2:

[image]

`CommandButton1` submits and `CommandButton2` quits out of the userform (Clicked when the user is done submitting, for instance).

The code to make this work as you described. This goes in the code page for the userform.

```
'declare a string array to hold the submissions from textbox1
Private submissions() As String

'Code to run when the form activates
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
    'When this userform is first initialized set up the array
    'as a one dimensional array with a single element
    ReDim submissions(0 To 0)
End Sub

'Code to run when the commandbutton1 is clicked
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    'call the addSubmission sub
    addSubmission
End Sub

'Code to run when the commandButton2 is clicked
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

    'add submission one more time
    addSubmission

    'Now Loop through the array and send the values out
    'to the worksheet
    Dim rowCounter As Long
    rowCounter = 1
    For Each submission In submissions
        Sheet1.Cells(rowCounter, 1).Value = submission
        rowCounter = rowCounter + 1
    Next submission

    'Now close the form
    Me.Hide

    'And activate sheet1 for the user to see their submissions
    Sheet1.Activate
End Sub

'addSubmission will add textBox1 value to
'  the submissions array declared at the
'  top of this userform code.
Sub addSubmission()
    'First we have to redim the array to hold the new
    '   submission.
    'But only redim it if this isn't the first submission
    If UBound(submissions) > 0 Or submissions(0) <> "" Then ReDim Preserve submissions(0 To UBound(submissions) + 1)
    submissions(UBound(submissions)) = Me.TextBox1.Value

    'Clear the textbox so the user doesn't have to backspace
    Me.TextBox1.Value = ""
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I needed!